# how can i acieve the following code in java

Tags: java, json

this code is in php where there are different type of json objects in an array

```
function data($text, $number, $user_id, $port = NULL, $encoding = NULL)
    {
    $data = array
    (
        "text" => "#param#",
        "param" => array
        (
            array(
            "number" => $number,
            "text_param" => array($text),
            "user_id" => $user_id,
            ),
        ),
    );
    if ($port != NULL) {
        $data["port"] = array($port);
    }

    if ($encoding != NULL) {
        $data["encoding"] = $encoding;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

what are the possible ways to write the above code in java

Comment: You didn't post what problem you are having.  You're just trying to get someone else to do your work.

Comment: If you pay me well enough, I'll do your work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't look for direct, native support of translating json straight into Java objects, it needs to be done through libraries.

There are a (quite big) number of json libraries - [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) is one that I used, [java EE json support](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsonp002.htm) is another. Search for others using your preferred search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library to parse JSON to Java object.